# How to use search bar without deleting rows in jQuery DataTables plugin?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I'm using the jQuery DataTables plugin to sort and search a table.

The table is inside a form and each row of this table has an input to select the number of the note linked to it, working as a batch, and when sending the data, the form selects all input and sends the values ​​as an array to another page .

The problem is that when using the search bar to look for the note number, it deletes the other lines, and consequently deletes the input...

Would there be a way to use the search bar, without deleting the lines? Just putting it as "display:none;"

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example?

Comment: What do you mean it is deleting the rows? By default it filters them out to match your search, then on search clear they are shown again?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.